# how to preg match all for jsondecode with php

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match-all

I have the follow string that I need to parse, and then run it through `json_decode`. My code is as follows. Right now I can't use `json_decode` because I am not able to properly parse the string it has more than one instance of json and i need to have the `preg_match_all` break it up like so {}, {}, {}.

**CODE**

```
$source = getHTML($URL); //get page source with curl
preg_match('/var\smessages\s\=\s\[(.*?)\]\;/', $source , $json);

echo $json_final = json_decode($json[0]);
echo $json_final_2 = json_decode($json[1]);
```

Comment: Why you don't group the [] too in `preg_match`? So you can use `json_decode` and get an array.

Comment: @David Rodrigues well its more than one set of json data so even if i do that `json_decode` can't read it

Comment: Take a look if is what you need: http://codepad.viper-7.com/w33ykR

Comment: Ahh... you say that exists more than one `var messages`?

Comment: If I'm right, just use the `preg_match_all`. Here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NnnKn1 (note the `array[1]` matches)

Comment: @David Rodrigues yes that's exactly what i wanted!! :)

Comment: @David Rodrigues can you show me how to call the values in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all`, accepting the `[` and `]` on group too (regex: `/var\smessages\s\=\s(\[.*?\])\;/`). So you will have zero or more JSON valid string syntax at `array[1]` (after `json_decode`).

Now to you call this values, you can use `foreach`:

```
foreach($json[1] as $messages) {
    $messages = json_decode($messages, true);
    foreach($messages as $message) {
        // Do what you need with the message here!
        echo "{$message[CreationTime]}: {$message[MessageText]}<br />";
    }
}
```

Note that the `json_decode` receives `true` on 2nd arg. It say to this function that need return an array, instead of an object (`stdClass`).

Take a look: http://codepad.viper-7.com/XtAiBH